Why does my script's output change when run manually vs via task scheduler
While my script runs both ways, when run through task scheduler, it messes up on an if-else statement. It's supposed to send out an email when it detects that there are fewer than three objects in a directory and creates a pdf with letters for patients when there are three or more files in that directory (two folders and a variable amount of patient data files). The issue that I'm running into is that when it's running through task scheduler, it creates a blank pdf when there's no patient data instead of sending out the email. Has anyone else run into similar issues?
Here is how it's set up in Task Scheduler:

Runs whether user is logged in or not, at the highest privileges
Runs weekly, on weekdays in the morning (a time when I'm usually logged on doing something)
Start program details: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "PRG"
Starts only when a network connection is available
Special settings:

Task can be run on demand
Runs as soon as scheduled task is missed
If it fails, restarts every 10 minutes
Restarts up to 3 times
Stops if running longer than 8 hours
Can be force stopped



Code for testing:
cd 'A:\Data Sources\Provider'
$Sources = dir
cd 'U:\'

if($Sources.Length -lt 3) {
    
    $mess = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application

    $mail = $mess.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.Subject = "SAMPLE SUBJECT"
    $mail.Body = "SAMPLE MESSAGE"
    $mail.To = "example@example.com"
    $mail.Send()

} 
else {
    ## Simplified this part due to its length and function calls

    & "DATA-CONVERSION-PRG.lnk"
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 60000

    $Data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SERVERNAME" -Database "DB" -TrustServerCertificate -Query "SELECT * FROM dbo.NegPap"

    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $True
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
    $Selection = $Word.Selection

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Data.Count; $i++) {
        $Selection.TypeText(Data.Get($i))
    }

    $date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
    $SavePath = "C:\path\" + $date + ".pdf"
    $Document.ExportAsFixedFormat($SavePath,17,$false,0,0,0,0,0,$false,$false,0,$false,$true)
    $Document.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    $Word.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
    Remove-Variable Word

    $NewPath = "\\fileserver\new-path\" + $date + ".pdf"
    Move-Item -Path $SavePath -Destination $NewPath
}


EDIT:
It seems like the main issue I was having was that the interop for outlook does not work if not running in the interactive session. Since this script is set to run whether I'm logged in or not, it wouldn't work whether or not the if/else was functional. I'm currently looking for a workaround.

Add debug statements that log paths and data element counts and whatnot. Also, there are unusual drive letters such as A: and U:, which might indicate network drives mapped during logon. Do those exist in scheduled session too?

I had assumed as much; it was running fine for a couple days. I'll run a few checks on this.

Per @vonPryz, if the “A:” drive isn’t available inside the scheduled task, the cd will fail anddir will return whatever’s in the default directory - if there’s 3 or more files wherever that is your code will execute the “false” branch, but there’s probably no data in the database at that point so it generates an empty output. Consider using $sources = Get-ChildItem -Path “A:\Data Sources\Provider” instead and handle any exceptions appropriately - that’ll ensure you test the count of files in the correct directory.

@mclayton I ended up switching to the full name, including the file server (\something\path), to get around the drive not being in there upon task scheduler logging in. It looks like I'll need to be relying on interactive sessions though, due to using the outlook interop.
